# Right method to declare a struct as member in another struct

Tags: c++, struct

Recently, I've asked a question about how to declare a struct member in another struct:

[How to allocate memory for struct as member in other struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69233545/)

My question was marked as a duplicate. But really, do I need to initialize all members with default values?

In my project code base, the struct has 3 such members. And when I describe all struct members with default values, the Member Initializer List reaches three very long code lines.

Is this way right?

```cpp
struct A
{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;
    int g;
    int h;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    A(int c_a, int c_b, int c_c, int c_d, int c_e, int c_f, int c_g, int c_h, int c_i, int c_j, int c_k)
    {
        a = c_a;
        b = c_b;
        c = c_c;
        d = c_d + 3;
        e = c_e;
        f = c_f;
        g = c_g - 9;
        h = c_h;
        i = c_i * 4;
        j = c_j;
        k = c_k;
    }
};

struct B
{
public:
    A a;

    B(A c_a) : a{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    {
        a = c_a;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    A a = A(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11); 
    B b = B(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this constructor "works":

```cpp
B(A c_a) : a{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
{
    a = c_a;
}
```

It is needlessly complex, as it initializes `a` with default values, just to overwrite it with new values afterwards.

At the very least, you could give `A` a [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) that initializes the members to 0:

```cpp
A()
{
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
    d = 0;
    e = 0;
    f = 0;
    g = 0;
    h = 0;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = 0;
}
```

And then your `B` constructor can omit the Member Initialization List:

```cpp
B(A c_a) /*: a{}*/
{
    a = c_a;
}
```

However, `B`'s constructor can and should utilize `A`'s [compiler-generated copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) instead, to avoiding having the initialize `a` with default zeros at all:

```cpp
B(A c_a) : a{c_a}
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it looks a little strange for me. Just imagine: you have a struct with 5 native types and 5 custom types. And then in that struct you need to initialize 5 fields via constructor function and 5 via constructor specialization. Looks like a strange mix where you can easily get confused. May be is a default constructor better approach? Just I don't know how c++ will process the member. Will init struct instance created? Need to deallocate that instance?

Comment: @WusikiJeronii sounds like you have more questions which should be posted separately so they can get their own answers.

Comment: Thank you. After editing your question I figured out why I would need to specialize a struct instance instead of calling a default constructor.